# how can I read "htm" file inside of zip folder in python?

Tags: python

not html, in "htm" file, how can I read in python?

for example,

A.htm is in the B folder which is inside of C zip file (C/B/A.htm)

Comment: This has nothing to do with HTML or the `.htm` file extension. The Python code would be the same for any file extension.

Answer (score 2):

The `ZipFile` class in the standard library supports accessing individual files in a ZIP archive, using `ZipFile.open` or `ZipFile.extract`:

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile("C.zip") as zf:
    with zf.open("C/B/A/.htm") as fp:
        a_binary = fp.read()

# You will need to know the file encoding,
# to convert the binary data to text.

a_text = a_binary.decode("utf-8")
```

Refer to the documentation for more details:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extract

Note that the file extension of `.htm` is completely irrelevant to the task at hand. The ZIP file format does not do anything with file extensions.